# Content files return "empty" on SSL connection

Tags: javascript, css, iis-7, https, windows-server-2008

I have two websites in IIS7 (WS2008) that points to the exact same folder on my server. The standard website (http://example.com) uses a normal HTTP protocol. However I have issued a SSL certificate to a subdomain (https://ssl.example.com) on the other website and it's on this protocol I'm having troubles.

On the HTTPS website some of my files just return empty or "nothing". Take for example my general CSS or JavaScript files. They work fine on my HTTP website, but on the HTTPS website they are just empty.

Am I missing a configuration in the IIS or am I just stupid? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I just had an analog situation that might pertain to yours. In our case the server has .gz (compressed) versions of html and js and these were empty due to the way the build was deployed. It might also happen that your web server is not configured to serve the .gz files up to the client with the correct file type in HTTP.